# AngularJS: renew token with interceptor (using service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have such interceptor code:

```
var responseError = function(rejection) {
if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403) {
authService.renewToken($localStorage.refreshToken).then(function () {
          });
        }
}
```

and sure, in the head of this code i include authService "injector", like

```
    ['$q', '$injector', '$location', '$localStorage', '$rootScope', '$window', 'authService', 
 function($q, $injector, $location, $localStorage, $rootScope, $window, authService) {...
```

and in service i have such code:

```
var renewToken = function(token) {
  var data = /**/
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post('token', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

but when i fall in this code, i get:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- authService <- authInterceptorService <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $route`

how could i renew my token, when i get exception in interceptor?

Comment: Try getting `$http` with the `$injector` : `$injector.get('$http').post(..`

Comment: @devqon maybe a little bit more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interceptor you don't have to include `authService`, inject only the `$injector`

your responseError function should be something like this:

```
var responseError = function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403) {
        var authService = $injector.get('authService');
        authService.renewToken($localStorage.refreshToken).then(function () {
        });
    }
}
```

This is a workaround through circular dependency error.